# R: Create a categorical variable when probability is given

Tags: r, variables, distribution

I have two dataframes that can be reproduced with the following code:

```
df=data.frame(xcode=c("612","920","924","925"),
              ratio.company1=c("0.1","0.9","0.4","0"),
              ratio.company2=c("0.1","0","0.6","0.6"),  
              ratio.company3=c("0.8","0.1","0","0.4"))
df

df2=data.frame(id=c("101","101","101","101","101","101","102","102","102","102","102","103","103","104","104","104","104","104","104","104","104","105","105","105","106","106","106","106","106","106","107","107","107","107","107","107"),
       xcode=c("612","612","612","612","612","612","612","612","612","612","612","920","920","920","920","920","920","920","920","920","920","924","924","924","924","924","924","924","924","924","925","925","925","925","925","925"),
       company=c(""))
df2
```

df gives me the probability of a person being assigned to company1 or company 2 or Company 3 based on the xcode field. df2 gives me IDs and xcodes. Based on the ratios given by xcodes, IDs in df2 need to be divided into company 1,2,3.

For example out of 11 IDs with xcode 612, 10 pct are assiged to company 1, 10 pct are assigned to company 2,and 80 pct are assigned to company3. I want to round up my result to 0 decimal places. I am unable to think of a way to achieve this. Can I use the `runif` command in someway that will do this? Please help.

My resulting dataset would look like this:

```
df2=data.frame(id=c("101","101","101","101","101","101","102","102","102","102","102","103","103","104","104","104","104","104","104","104","104","105","105","105","106","106","106","106","106","106","107","107","107","107","107","107"),
       xcode=c("612","612","612","612","612","612","612","612","612","612","612","920","920","920","920","920","920","920","920","920","920","924","924","924","924","924","924","924","924","924","925","925","925","925","925","925"),
       company=c("company1","company2","company3","company3","company3","company3","company3","company3","company3","company3","company3",
                 "company1","company1","company1","company1","company1","company1","company1","company1","company1","company3",
                 "company1","company1","company1","company1","company2","company2","company2","company2","company2",
                 "company2","company2","company2","company2","company3","company3"))
```

Comment: what is the desired output ?

Comment: @MamounBenghezal: commend edited with the desired result. thanks!

Comment: maybe something like `round(9/11, digits = 1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

This would deliver on one possible interpretation of your request:

```
c('comp1','comp2','comp3')[
                  findInterval( runif(36) , 
                                c(0, cumsum( as.numeric(as.character(df[1,2:4]))) ))]
#-----------
 [1] "comp3" "comp3" "comp3" "comp3" "comp2" "comp3" "comp3" "comp3" "comp3"
[10] "comp3" "comp3" "comp3" "comp2" "comp3" "comp1" "comp3" "comp1" "comp3"
[19] "comp1" "comp3" "comp3" "comp3" "comp3" "comp2" "comp3" "comp3" "comp1"
[28] "comp3" "comp3" "comp3" "comp3" "comp3" "comp3" "comp2" "comp3" "comp3"
```

My experience with answering similar questions in the past is that there is often an unspoken expectation of exactly 0.1,0.1 and 0.8 as proportions, and this does not deliver on that expectation. If you wanted to get exactly (or almost exactly, since 10% of 36 is not an integer) in those proportions, you would need to use `rdirichlet` rather than `runif`. Or you could use `sample` on a vector of `c(rep('comp1', 3), rep('comp2', 4), rep('comp3', 29))`.

Comment: using your code, my output is comp1 for all 36 rows. Would you have any idea why? thanks!

Comment: Bad luck? Reminding me of the line: "If I didn't have bad luck, I wouldn't have no luck at all".

Comment: I just ran it again and got: 32 comp3; 1 comp1; and 3 comp2. I warned you  that you might not be happy with true randomness.